# How to retrieve height and width properties of a png file in perl

Tags: perl, png

I have a link to a png file and I want to retrieve image properties like width and height.
I have never done this before. I have take a look at GD but I could not  find any method for resolving my issue.

here is  an example of a png file

```
http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/map/map00010.png
```

Comment: [Image::Size](http://search.cpan.org/~rjray/Image-Size-3.232/lib/Image/Size.pm)

Answer (score 3):

Using the Image::PNG::Libpng library you could:

```
 use LWP::Simple;
 my $image_data = get 'http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/map/map00010.png';
 my $png = create_read_struct();
 $png->read_from_scalar ($image_data);
 my $IHDR = $png->get_IHDR();
 print "Image size " . $IHDR{'width'} . " x " . $IHDR{'height'} . "\n";
```

Comment: It says Global symbol "%IHDR" requires explicit package name at tt.pl line 8.I have added use strict and use warnings so in your code is line 6

Comment: That code isn't very clean, I'm assuming you can figure out how to use the Image::PNG::Libpng library and import it into your code.

Comment: Change `$IHDR{'width'}` to `$IHDR->{'width'}`, same for height.

Answer (score 3):

```
use Image::Size;

 my $image_URL="http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/map/map00010.png";
 my $pngfile="data.pang";
 getstore($image_URL,"$pngfile");         
 my($globe_x, $globe_y) = imgsize("$pngfile");
 print "x is $globe_x, y is $globe_y";
```

result is

```
x is 716, y is 1020
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another example using the `Image::Info` module:

```
use LWP::Simple qw(get);
use Image::Info qw(image_info dim);
my $image_URL = "http://www.kegg.jp/kegg/pathway/map/map00010.png";
my $image_data = get($image_URL);
my($x, $y) = dim(image_info(\$image_data));
print "x is $x, y is $y\n";
```